Large Text from accessibility settings won't turn off in ubuntu 24.04
I was using my laptop with the large text option on for a few days and decided to turn it off but it didn't in the top bar it toggles on/off but the text on the screen never reverts to it's original size.
I have tried logging out and logging in, restarting but nothing helped. In the login screen the option works tough but only that far.
How can I fix it?

is this question related to your issue? In particular the command in terminal gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0

yes thank you it works, also the accessibility icon goes away when I set it to 1.0 and comes back when I set it to 1.25. Hopefully, this bug will get fixed in the next update cause it would be convenient to just use the toggle button.

Thanks for the feedback. I'll close vote your question as a dupe accordingly - perhaps you'd also like to upvote that answer which will help others with the same issue find a solution.

@graham yeah you can close this as a dupe, I've upvoted the answer there but I need at least 15 rep for it to show so it has been recorded for now.

Solution 1: First go to the setting > Accessibility > toggle off "Always show Accessibility Menu" > again toggle on then try it again if than wouldn't ....
Try it manually by ...Accessibility > Seeing > Toggle OFF "Large Text"
Solution 2 : Download Tweak Application to change the size of the Text according to you .

I tried solution 1 but still nothing, so weird. I know changing the font size manually would work but well... thanks for sharing
